# How can I remove border in ion-card in ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view

I've try many way to remove the border in my ion-card, but it not successfully. Please help me.
Here is my css file:

```
   page-home {
     ion-card, .card-ios, .card-md {
        border: 0 !important;
        box-shadow: 0 !important;
        border: none !important;
        border-style: none !important;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        // border-top: 3px solid colorofyourchosing
      }
      .card{
        border: 0 !important;
        box-shadow: 0 !important;
        border: none !important;
        border-style: none !important;
      }    }
```

Here is my html code in home.html

```
            <ion-card>
              <img (click)="goEnvi()" src="assets/imgs/envi.svg"/>
              <h6>{{"Enviroment" | translate}}</h6>
            </ion-card>
```

Thanks you

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz that shows the problem?

Comment: have you tried `box-shadow: none; webkit-box-shadow: none;` ?

Comment: Thanks you Leo, box-shadow: none; is worked for me. 
Ionic doesnt know webkit-box-shadow property.

Comment: @Desperado Good to know, I was not aware of it. I wrote the answer in an official way

Answer (score 24):

In your css file change

```
 box-shadow: 0 !important;
```

to

```
box-shadow: none !important;
```

Comment: This works on Ionic 4 too. Thanks. I hope you can accept this answer.

Comment: Works in Ionic 6 as well. Example if you want a simple border instead: 

<ion-card style="box-shadow: none !important;border: 1px solid black;"> 
    My Content 
</ion-card>

Comment: For me in Ionic 5, it works with `border: 0px;` without and no `box-shadow`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.card
{
box-shadow:none !important
}
```